# Removing .html on paths with htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the `.html` off the end of all my links, for example `www.mywebsite.com/contact.html` should be `www.mywebsite.com/contact`

The following code does the job:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I also want my directory files to remove the `.html` too, i.e. `www.mywebsite.com/rates/index.html` should be `www.mywebsite.com/rates`

It is working with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]
```

But together, they don't work. If the second sits underneath the 1st only the 1st works. If I only have the second option my 1st doesn't work and all my links are broken. How do I combine the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on

    # to make `/path/index.html` to /path/
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.html [NC]
    RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Was actually a lot more complicated than I thought. I can't mark the answer as correct yet (have to wait 8 minutes) but as soon as I can I will.